# How to create a specific user on a specific host

Tags: ansible

There are several computers on the network, on each of them you need to create a user with a specific login and password.

I create users like this:

```
vars_prompt:
 - name: "user_name"
   prompt: "User name"    
   private: no   
 - name: "user_password"    
   prompt: "Enter a password for the user"    
   private: yes    
   encrypt: "md5_crypt"    
   confirm: yes    
   salt_size: 7
tasks:
 - name: "add new user" 
   user: 
     name: "{{user_name}}" 
     password: "{{user_password}}" 
     shell: /bin/bash
```

Since there are many computers I don’t want to run a playbook a huge number of times. Ideally, I would like to implement the input of the list of hosts (computers) and the list of users. Password, in principle, you can do the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the task

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: "add new user" 
    user: 
      name: "{{ item.user_name }}" 
      password: "{{ item.user_password }}" 
      shell: /bin/bash
    loop: "{{ my_users }}"
```

and put the variable(s) *my_users* to [host_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html?highlight=host_vars)

```yaml
my_users:
  - user_name: user1
    user_password: password1
  - user_name: user2
    user_password: password2
```

- Put common users to [group_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html?highlight=group_vars#group-and-host-variables).
- See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)
- Use [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) to encrypt the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can try. Adapt to your needs.

Note: if the list of users is different for each host, just execute the playbook several times. Implementing this as a promptable play in ansible will just be a total pain and merely unusable.

In the example below, `test1` and `test2` are pointing to 2 docker containers I added in my `demo_inventory.yml`.

```
all:
  hosts:
    test1:
      ansible_connection: docker
    test2:
      ansible_connection: docker
```

The hosts you enter will need to be correctly known by ansible for this to work.

This is the demo playbook `test.yml`

```
---
- name: Gather needed information
  hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:

    - name: hosts_entry
      prompt: Enter comma separated list of hosts to target
      private: false

    - name: users_entry
      prompt: Enter comma separated list of users to create
      private: false

    - name: user_password
      prompt: Enter initial password applied to all users
      encrypt: md5_crypt
      confirm: true
      salt_size: 7


  tasks:
    - name: Create a dynamic whatever_group with entered hosts
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item | trim }}"
        groups:
          - whatever_group
      loop: "{{ hosts_entry.split(',') }}"

    - name: Create a list of host for later reuse. Will be scoped to localhost
      set_fact:
        users_list: "{{ users_entry.split(',') }}"

    - name: Store password for later reuse as vars_prompt are limited to play
      set_fact:
        user_password: "{{ user_password }}"

 - name: Do the actual work
   hosts: whatever_group

   tasks:
     - name: Make sure users are present
       user:
         name: "{{ item | trim }}"
         password: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].user_password }}"
         shell: /bin/bash
       loop: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].users_list }}"
```

I created a play on localhost to gather the info from `vars_prompt`. In this play, I used `add_host` to create a `whatever_group` dynamically. Note the use of `split` to create list from a string with comma seperated elements in the input and of `trim` to remove the leading/trailing spaces (if user entered them). Since `vars_prompt` are limited in scope to the current play, I also used `set_fact` to get the users list and the password for future use.

On the next play, I target the `whatever_group` and run the `user` task. Note that since `set_fact` used previously scoped the variables to `localhost`, we have to use the `hostvars` magic variable to get the relevant information for the user `loop` and the password.

Here is the example run

```
$ ansible-playbook -i demo_inventory.yml test.yml 
Enter comma separated list of hosts to target: test1, test2
Enter comma separated list of users to create: user1, user2, user3
Enter initial password applied to all users: 
confirm Enter initial password applied to all users: 

PLAY [Gather needed information] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create a dynamic whatever_group with entered hosts] **************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=test1)
changed: [localhost] => (item= test2)

TASK [Create a list of host for later reuse. Will be scoped to localhost] **********************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Store password for later reuse as vars_prompt are limited to play] ***********************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [Do the actual work] **********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************
ok: [test1]
ok: [test2]

TASK [Make sure users are present] *************************************************************
changed: [test2] => (item=user1)
changed: [test1] => (item=user1)
changed: [test2] => (item= user2)
changed: [test1] => (item= user2)
changed: [test2] => (item= user3)
changed: [test1] => (item= user3)

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test1                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test2                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```